# Rails 3: How to set the Devise login like root

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my routes I try with:

```
authenticated :user do
   root :to => "dashboard#show"
end

root :to => "devise/sessions#new"
```

But I have a beatiful browser error:

```
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)
```

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change which action the root_path points to you can do something like in your routes file:

```
  devise_for :users

  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'pages#home'
  end

  root :to => 'pages#welcome'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code in my routes file. I'm adding users under `devise_for` and rooting to the page I want users to go after login

```
devise_for :users

root :to => 'account#index'

resources :devise
```